# How to loop through me/friends and assign each user it's picture from {USERID}/picture from FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, design-patterns

Using javascript  I get list of facebook friends though it only returns name and id now, but I need to get the picture of each user. I try to loop through the response and then try to call the api to get picture, but due to it's async call I can't associate the returned picture with the index of the friend in the array. *this is kinda a problem that I've had with asynchronous programming in general, is there a standard pattern for this?

Example.

```
FB.api('me/friends', function(response) {
    if(response.error == null){
        var friendsSale = response.data;
        var len = friendsSale.length;
        for(var x=0; x<len; x++){               
                FB.api(friendsSale[x].id+'/picture', function(response) {
                    //x no longer is the same x as the initial call, and I can't pass in the orignal array object into the FB.api function to return as part of the response... or can I?
                    friendsSale[x].pictureUrl = response;
                });
            }
        }
        //Then how do I know when I have all the pictures set so I can then set datamodle with the complete friend array?
        m.friends(friendsSale);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a pattern for this: a [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
    ...
    var len = friendsSale.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        (function() {
            var j = i;             
            FB.api(friendsSale[i].id+'/picture', function(response) {
                friendsSale[j].pictureUrl = response;
            });
        })();
    }
```

To know when all all calls have returned you can simply keep a counter of returned calls, e.g.

```
    ...
    var len = friendsSale.length;
    var returnedCallsCounter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        (function() {
            var j = i;             
            FB.api(friendsSale[i].id+'/picture', function(response) {
                friendsSale[j].pictureUrl = response;

                // Track number of returned calls
                returnedCallsCounter++;

                // Check if all calls have returned
                if (returnedCallsCounter == len) {
                    m.friends(friendsSale);
                }
            });
        })();
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant that was it, and now I have a tool for similar tasks.
Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: Its really great, You gave me just what I was looking for from many days. Thanks Julian.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for you :
All you have to do is query this :
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture
and you will get the users profile picture.  For example :
Querying `https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture` (with no access token BTW - try it in chrome <strike>pron</strike> incognito mode) :
`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture">`

will yeild this smiling face :
[image]

*Now you know Marks fbid :P*

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I am trying to have my model handle the user information and not the view/html

Comment: You can simply use the URL as the value for the picture.  You don't have to use it in HTML - I put it like that just as an example.