# Facebook javascript sdk get the total number of friends of a user

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/friends",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

From this code, how do I get the number of the list?
I'm interested of getting the total number of friends from a user that use my app.

Comment: What did you try? What did `response` look like?

Comment: I don't know almost nothing about javascript, so I don't know... maybe the response should look like this:
{ "data" : [{"name": "barack obama", id: "123456"}, {"name": "michelle johnson", id: "63479"}]}

Comment: Well, I know that I have to get the length of that array, but I don't know how...

Comment: "Should look like?" Why don't you try it and see what it actually looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The friends array is in `response.data`. To get the length of the array, just use `response.data.length`

See [How to loop through me/friends and assign each user it's picture from {USERID}/picture from FB.api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057109/how-to-loop-through-me-friends-and-assign-each-user-its-picture-from-userid-p)

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/friends",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log('Friend count = ', response.data.length);
      }
    }
);
```

[1]:

Answer (score 1):

Juan is mostly correct.

The only thing I would also recommend is setting the limit to something greater than what you'd expect or walk across the paging:next url.

```
"paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx/friends?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=xxxxxx"
  }
```

The default limit is 5000 and while this would usually not be a problem for normal users, celebrities, businesses, etc might have more friends that this.

```
/friends?limit=10000000000
```

Comment: thank you that's a great idea I didn't know I could set this!